# body.set Angular2 post file to a third party

Tags: angular

I need to POST a small file to a third party server. I already posted the fields they required and that worked perfect, but I dont know how to set the file with body.set

Here is my code on the .ts:

```
    var APIURL = sessionStorage.getItem('endpoint') + "/setattributes";    
    let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') };
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('id', this.id);
    body.set('session', encodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem('session')));
    body.set('token', encodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem('token')));
    body.set('channel', encodeURIComponent(channel));

    this.httpClient.post(APIURL, body.toString(), options).subscribe(

      result => { .....
```

And here is my HTML

```
<input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)" class="NiceUpload" id="file" accept=".log">
```

They are saying I need to POST the file as Im posting the rest of the fields and call it "logfile", but body.set is not working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is suggested to add a value to the option variable

withCredentials: true

```
let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'), withCredentials: true};
```